ERROR 1714114699.725235045 transformPoseInTargetFrame : Extrapolation Error looking up target frame:
I am doing this on my machine and controllers are running on rpi 4b unable to perform navigation robot starting spinning around
Error:
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1714114699.420264777] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (-0.04, 0.13) to (2.23, -0.48)
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1714114699.725235045] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1714114699.418548 but the latest data is at time 533.559000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1714114699.725322634] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1714114699.725393194] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714114699.740877971] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1714114700.877249327] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1714114699.418548 but the latest data is at time 534.659000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1714114700.877337774] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1714114700.877429145] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1714114700.890988285] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1714114700.891849250] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1714114701.878170952] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1714114699.418548 but the latest data is at time 535.659000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]

For rviz2:
Start navigation
[INFO] [1714114699.419051504] [rviz_navigation_dialog_action_client]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigator's default behavior tree.
[INFO] [1714114699.570008045] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114682.565 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114699.922159323] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114693.899 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114700.529242380] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114694.499 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114700.593508340] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114684.565 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114701.105576313] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114695.099 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114701.714070310] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114695.699 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114702.321509604] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114696.299 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114702.577622641] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114685.567 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[INFO] [1714114702.929899067] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'map' at time 1714114696.899 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'


You are requesting a transform at time 1714114699.418548, but only transforms at time 533.559000 are available. The latter seems to me to be a simulation time (only 500 seconds old) while the former seems to me system time.
So you are probably not using use_sim_time somewhere.
If you add SetParameter("use_sim_time", LaunchConfiguration("use_sim_time")) inside a GroupAction it will parse the parameter to all inlcuded launch files and Nodes within your GroupAction.
Don't forget to declare use_sim_time as a launch argument though.
Alternatively you can use wild cards in your parameter file to parse the use_sim_time parameter to all nodes like:
/**:
   ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: true


I already have this in launch file

It seems to be the planner_server that is trying the erroneous lookup. Cehck ros2 param get /planner_server /use_sim_time in the command line. Also make sure that rviz2 is running on sim time, I see you run it from a different instance. That is important because it publishes the goal pose, that needs to be at the correct time.
